# Expect json array in AJAX

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, while-loop

How is it possible for me to get my Ajax to expect my array within my success. Currently I presume I use a flat object and this needs to grab all the data passed back to the client side so I can update my notifications.

I presume everything else is correct!

```
    {"num":1,"670":{"notification_id":"670","notification_content":"
    Lucy  Botham posted a status on your
    wall","notification_throughurl":"singlepoststreamitem.php?
    streamitem_id=545","notification_triggeredby"
    "85","notification_status":"1"},"671":
    {"notification_id":"671","notification_content":"Lucy  Botham
    posted a status on your 
    wall","notification_throughurl":"singlepoststreamitem.php?streamitem_id=546"
   ,"notification_triggeredby":"85","notification_status":"1"}}
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($com)){
    $id = $row['notification_id'];
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($com);
    if($num){
        $json['num'] = 1;
    }else{
        $json['num'] = 0;
    }
    $json[$id]['notification_id'] = $row['notification_id'];
    $json[$id]['notification_content'] = $row['notification_content'];
    $json[$id]['notification_throughurl'] = $row['notification_throughurl'];
    $json[$id]['notification_triggeredby'] = $row['notification_triggeredby'];
    $json[$id]['notification_status'] = $row['notification_status'];
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

**CLIENT**

```
        function loadIt() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "viewajax.php?    
        notification_id="+notification_id+"
        &notification_targetuser="+notification_targetuser+
       "&notification_triggeredby="+notification_triggeredby,   
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(data){
       //do something 
       )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `json.parse()`

```
success: function(data){
     var a = JSON.parse(data);
     //loop var a to get your data 
}
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_parse) link, you might get some idea.

Comment: would a be data.notification_id

Comment: `a` is an array now. it shud be `a[0].notification_id`

Comment: Thank you, Just what I was looking for.